# Loop by Object inside another Object in Java

Tags: java, list, oop, collections

I'm not sure how to ask this in word so here's an example :

Building class have a data like this :

```
Map<Season, List<Info>> infosBySeason = new TreeMap<Season, List<Info>>();
```

What I'd like to do is loop for each Building, print by Season infos.

Like :

```
Season 1 :
  Building 1 :
    Info 1, Info 2....
  Building 2 :
    Info 1, Info 2....

Season 2 :
  Building 1 :
    Info 1, Info 2....
  Building 2 :
    Info 1, Info 2....
```

Should I put Season as the outer class and duplicates Building for each Season?

Is there a nice way to deal with this kind of "many-to-many" relationship between classes?

Comment: Is Building inferred by the position in the List?

Comment: To answer your question: in a way, Collections are lower-level than a database; you don't get indexes, per se, so you structure your data according to how you're going to look it up. The duplication issue also exists in a relational database (that's how indexes work), only now you're managing them on your own. Basically, if you're looking up by `Seasion` *and* `Building`, you're getting a bit beyond what Collections are good at.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Not sure what you mean by your first question. Is there a general strategy to deal with this outside of using Collections?

Comment: "getting a bit beyond what **the built-in** Collections are good at." If you're not averse to using outside collections libraries, you could look at [Apache Collections'](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) implementation of [MultiKeyMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html). It sounds like you're something of a novice so maybe this isn't for you, but it's still worth mentioning, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve the problem, seasonMap contains values in the order you need (assuming classes implement Comparable)

```
Map<Season, Map<Building, List<Info>>> seasonMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Building building : buildings) {
    for (Map.Entry<Season, List<Info>> e : building.infosBySeason.entrySet()) {
        Season season = e.getKey();
        List<Info> infos = e.getValue();
        if (!seasonMap.containsKey(season)) {
            seasonMap.put(season, new TreeMap<>());
        }

        seasonMap.get(season).put(building, infos);
    }
}
```

> Should I put Season as the outer class and duplicates Building for
>   each Season?

Bad idea, you will most likely get stuck with circular dependencies which are difficult to maintein.

> Is there a nice way to deal with this kind of "many-to-many"
>   relationship between classes?

Designing a better data model is a way to simplify the code. You can say that data model is good, if it effectively solves all your requirements. If you will use the loop, that you described 99% of time, then maybe it is better to make Building a member of Season class and invert the logic.

Answer (score -1):

This could be another idea, assuming you create classes

```
class Season implements Comparable<Season>
//....
class Building implements Comparable<Building> 
//.....
class Info
//....

Map<Season, Map<Building, List<Info>>> seasonMap = new TreeMap<>();
//initialize and put your values inside seasonMap 
//....

for(Season s: seasonMap.keySet()){
    System.out.println(s.toString()+":");
    Map<Building, List<Info>> map = seasonMap.get(s);
    for(Building b: map.keySet()){
        System.out.println("\t"+b.toString() + ":");
        List<Info> list = map.get(b);
        System.out.print("\t\t");
        for(Info info: list){
            System.out.print(info.toString() + ",");
        }
    }
}
```